# Multiple Coupled Differential Equation solution in Python

Tags: python, ode

I have 4 ordinary differential equations that are coupled. The variables in the 4 equations are functions of time and space and one of them is second order in space.

\begin{equation}
\frac{ \partial t_g}{ \partial t} = \frac {hp(t_m-tg)}{A(\rho_gCp_g)}- u\frac { \partial t_g}{ \partial x}   
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \partial t_m}{ \partial t} = \frac{k_{sub}A_{sub}}{(\rho_mA_mCp_m)+(\rho_{sub}A_{sub}Cp_{sub})}\frac{ \partial^2 t_m}{ \partial x^2} + \frac{ h_mp(\rho_{vg}-\rho_{vm})h_{ads}}{ (\rho_mA_mCp_m)+(\rho_{sub}A_{sub}Cp_{sub})} - \frac {hp(t_m-t_g)}{(\rho_mA_mCp_m)+(\rho_{sub}A_{sub}Cp_{sub}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac { \partial \rho_{vg}}{ \partial t} = - \frac {h_mp( \rho_{vg} -\rho_{vm})}{A} - \frac {u \partial \rho_{vg}}{ \partial x} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac { \partial \gamma_m}{ \partial t} = \frac {h_mp(\rho_{vg}-\rho_{vm})}{ \rho_mA_m}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac { \gamma_m}{ \gamma_{max}} = \frac {1}{1-c+ \frac{c}{ \phi}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\phi = 4.09(10^{-9})t_m\rho_{vm}(e^\frac{-5196}{t_m})
\end{equation}

$t_g$, $t_m$, $\rho_{vg}$, $\rho_{vm}$, and $\gamma_m$ are the variables.

I am looking to solve this in Python. What is the best way to proceed?

I have the Boundary and Initial Conditions corresponding to these equations. But, having never used Python to solve such a problem, I am unsure whether to use a function like `odeint` or to type out the forward difference scheme.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. Are you sure that you have a system of ODEs and not PDEs? Can you add your equations to the question?

Comment: (∂t_g)/∂t=(h*p*(t_m- t_g))/(A*ρ_g* Cp_g ) - (u∂t_g)/∂x

Comment: (∂t_m)/∂t = (k_sub*A_sub)/((ρ_m* A_m*Cp_m) + (ρ_sub* A_sub*Cp_sub))*(∂^2 t_m)/(∂x^2 ) +  (h_m*p*ρ_vg- ρ_vm)*h_ads)/((ρ_m* A_m*Cp_m)+(ρ_sub* A_sub*Cp_sub ) - (h*p*(t_m-) t_g))/((ρ_m* A_m*Cp_m)+(ρ_sub* A_sub*Cp_sub))

Comment: (∂ρ_vg)/∂t=-((h_m*p*(ρ_vg- ρ_vm))/A + u*(∂ρ_vg)/∂x)

Comment: (∂q_m)/∂t=(h_m*p)/((ρ_m* A_m))*(ρ_vg-ρ_vm)

Comment: t_g ,t_m ,ρ_vg,ρ_vm ,q_m are the variables ... q_m is a moisture loading measure ... there is an equation for that too . But if I understand how to simultaneously update the values then I think I can apply the same to solve that equation too . But these are the 4 basic governing equations . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please, add them to the question. You can use LaTeX syntax to format them.

Comment: I added the equations, please check that they are correctly typed.

Comment: You have 5 unknowns and 4 equations. The system is not an ODE as you stated before...

Comment: It seems an equation is missing, and you haven't specified whether this is a boundary or initial value problem (you seem to be saying it's both somehow...).  We won't be able to help you until you state the problem correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the delay , I have added all the equations that I have . As to the type of problem . For the differential in time I have Initial values and For the differentials in space I have boundary values . But since the equations are a function of time and one dimension I thought it would be an ODE. Am I mistaken ?

Comment: And thank you for the quick responses . Really need help on this one. Thanks Again guys

Comment: You have some typos in the equation, and you can group some of the factor as constants to simplify the notation.

Comment: $q_m$ is not used in any of the PDE, please add that equation, I assume all the initial condition and B.C are given. Descretize the spatial derivative using minimum two point formula, Now the set of equation become IVP, That can be solved using any time-integration solver. I prefer RK solvers over other time integration method because it can handle most of hyperbolic problem even if we use CD method in space.

Comment: Apologies , q is actually gamma as mentioned in the second from bottom equation . Is the syntax different to update values simultaneously rather than the order in which we input these equations ? Since these are coupled , I need all equations to solve for time step-0 before solving for higher time steps for all the points in space. Can someone post an example problem similar to this problem ? It would really help me see how my code should proceed . Thanks again guys :)

Comment: You might be interested to apply [nondimensionalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization) to your system of equations and collect all terms in some constants to remove the clutter from the equations and to bring variables in reasonable ranges. Then start with the discretization of the system as shown in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have a relation for $\gamma_m$:
$$
\gamma_m =  \frac {\alpha_7}{1-c+ \frac{c}{ \phi}} =: f(t_m, \rho_{vm}; t,x)
$$
which can be used to get an equation of the form
$$
  \frac{\partial \gamma_m}{\partial t} = \beta_\rho(t_m, \rho_{vm})\,\frac{\partial \rho_{vm}}{\partial t} + \beta_t(t_m, \rho_{vm})\,\frac{\partial t_m}{\partial t} + \beta_c(t_m, \rho_{vm})
$$
You can then use the expression for the derivative of $\gamma_m$ 
$$
\frac { \partial \gamma_m}{ \partial t} = \alpha_6(\rho_{vg}-\rho_{vm})
$$ 
to write
$$
 \frac{\partial \rho_{vm}}{\partial t} = \alpha(t_m,\rho_{vg},\rho_{vm})  + \beta(t_m, \rho_{vm})\,\frac{\partial t_m}{\partial t}
$$
Then the four equations that you have are
$$
 \begin{aligned}
\frac{ \partial t_g}{ \partial t} &= \alpha_1\,(t_m-t_g)- u\frac { \partial t_g}{ \partial x}  \\
\frac{ \partial t_m}{ \partial t} &= \alpha_2\frac{ \partial^2 t_m}{ \partial x^2} + \alpha_3(\rho_{vg}-\rho_{vm}) - \alpha_4(t_m-t_g)\\
\frac { \partial \rho_{vg}}{ \partial t} &= - \alpha_5( \rho_{vg} -\rho_{vm}) - u\frac {\partial \rho_{vg}}{ \partial x} \\
\frac{\partial \rho_{vm}}{\partial t} &= \alpha(t_m,\rho_{vg},\rho_{vm})  + \beta(t_m, \rho_{vm})\,\frac{\partial t_m}{\partial t}
\end{aligned}
$$
where $t_g$, $t_m$, $\rho_{vg}$, $\rho_{vm}$ are the variables you want to solve for.

Now imagine the spatial derivatives fixed so that these are ordinary differential equations with $t$ as the independent variable. You will still not be able to solve the system because only three of these equations are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Just discretize the all the spatial term of every equation.

Here i'm concentrating only first equation other equation should be done in similar style. 
Lets use [CD4](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/differentiation/numericaldiffproof.pdf) in space and RK4 in time because CD4 has good Dispersion preserving property and RK4 has relatively good stability. Please try to avoid Euler time integration at any cost if you are using central difference in space and the equation has dominant advection character because of stability issues.

Please note that we should use some lower order methods at boundary where we can't apply CD4 stencil else if the boundary is periodic we can apply CD4 over the whole domain.
\begin{equation}
\frac{ \partial t_g}{ \partial t} = \frac {hp(({t_m}_i-{t_g}_i)}{A(\rho_gCp_g)}- u\frac {  {t_g}_{i-2}-8*{t_g}_{i-1}+8{t_g}_{i+1}-{t_g}_{i+2}}{ 12*\delta x}   
\end{equation}

Form the initial condition you know $t_g$ and $t_m$ values in the domain at t=0 now we should march in time. 
Lets assume 
\begin{equation}
F= \frac {hp(({t_m}_i-{t_g}_i)}{A(\rho_gCp_g)}- u\frac {  {t_g}_{i-2}-8*{t_g}_{i-1}+8{t_g}_{i+1}-{t_g}_{i+2}}{ 12*\delta x}  
\end{equation}

This equation become

\begin{equation}
\frac{ d t_g}{ \partial t} =F(t_g)
\end{equation}

Using low [storage RK4 method](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021999180900339)
this will become

\begin{equation}
{t_g}^0 = {t_g}^n
\end{equation}
here you can substitute Initial condition value of $t_g$

${t_g}^1 = {t_g}^0 + \alpha_1 \delta t F({t_g}^0)$

${t_g}^2 = {t_g}^0+\alpha_2 \delta t F({t_g}^1)$

${t_g}^3 = {t_g}^0+\alpha_3 \delta t F({t_g}^2)$

${t_g}^4 = {t_g}^0 + \alpha_4 \delta t F({t_g}^3)$

${t_g}^{n+1}={t_g}^4 $

$\alpha_4=1/4$, $\alpha _3=1/3$, $\alpha _2=1/2$ and $\alpha _1=1$

Like this do this for other equation. Since we are not having any time derivative of $\rho_{vm}$ we should use those algebraic equations to calculate $\rho_{vm}$ using newly calculated other variables.

Please note that this kind of problem may cause dispersion and numerical diffusion so always use low CFL number -may be less than 0.5 and fine grid (this should be determined by trial and error if you know wave number of initial condition then it may be easy but most of the time we may not have single wave numbered initial condition).

Comment: Sorry right now I'm not having any sample code. I shall improve this answer when i get free time

Comment: Thanks for the tip on discretization !! That really helped . Won't the equation be a function of $t_g$ and $t_m$ ? And if so , both will vary with space and time again . The Initial condition is at t=0, at x=0 . To do a CD4 method discretization will the initial condition we have now be sufficient ?

Comment: Sorry i forget to mention, u could use lower order near boundary,where CD4 stencil can't be applied. For the first equation initial condition supposed to be $t_g(x,0)=f(x)$, Second equation requires two B.C and one initial condition. If initial condition is  provided like $t_g(0,0) =c$. We should assume some condition except boundary. In that case we are interested in only  steady state.

Comment: @Sanjeev For the first equation $t_m$ acts like source term. $t_g$ acts like source term in second equation. that I have discretized  in $F$